# java regex: word chracters and white spaces

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to combine the `\w` and `\s` classes. So the input should only contain letters, numbers and whitespaces.

I've already tried "`[\\w\\s]`" and "`\\w\\s`" and others. But they don't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"[\\w\\s]"` should work, can you post a code where it doesn't work.

Comment: As whitespace also newline characters like `\n` and `\r` are considered. `"...".split("[^\\w\\s]+")` gives an array of word-and-whitespace sequences.

Comment: @anubhava, this is my code: `if (!title.matches("[\\w\\s]")){ ... }`

Comment: `if (!title.matches("[\\w\\s]+")){ ... }`

Comment: You should use: `if (!title.matches("^[\\w\\s]+$")){ ... }` to check

Comment: @Joop Eggen & anubhava: Please answer questions as answers, not as comments to the question. You will get more reputation that way.

Answer (score 2):

You need `(?U)[\p{alnum}\s]`, under Java 7.  Otherwise it gets both those sets wrong, because it only works on ASCII otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe `(\\w|\\s)` to combine it. It means `\\w` `OR` `\\s`, but for me

```
    System.out.println("abc def ghi".replaceAll("[\\w\\s]", "X"));
    //out ->            XXXXXXXXXXX
```

works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[\w\s&&[^_]]+$
```

`\w` other than letters and numbers, also inclues underscore. You need to do a subtraction if don't want it.

- For `abc abc 123`: YES
- For `abc_abc 123`: NO

Comment: Remember that will only work on ASCII in Java 6. You need the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` or `(?U)` flag, and under Java 7, for those to work right. Anyway, why not just use `alnum`?